# SQL using GROUP BY or DISTINCT to get back first records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table like this:

```
group        id
1            10
1            11
1            12
2            13
3            14
```

I want to get back the first record of each group, so my table should return something like this:

```
group        id
1            10
2            13
3            14
```

What's the best way to do this in SQL?

Comment: is it safe to assume that earlier record will always have smaller id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
SELECT group, min(id) id FROM table
GROUP BY group
```

Take into account that for "first" this is considering the minimal number.

Comment: using `min` will **not** guarantee to get back the **first** record of each group

Answer (score -1):

Group by will only return the first row of each group. So group by will enough

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY group
```

sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2673c/3

Comment: this doesn't work because the question stated i need both group and id returned, so id needs to either been in the group by clause returning 5 rows (not what was asked) or aggregated like in the selected answer

Comment: hi @chirs , maybe I miss understand what you want, but have you try to run that query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2673c/3 Note that min() will not select **first record of each group**

Comment: it doesn't work like that in sql server 2005, not sure what sql fiddle uses